# Suppose $p, q, n\in\Bbb N$. If $\frac pq\in(0,\frac 1n)$, show that $\frac 1q\in(0,\frac 1n)$.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $p, q, n\in\Bbb N$. If $\frac pq\in(0,\frac 1n)$, show that $\frac 1q\in(0,\frac 1n)$.

I am currently self studying real analysis and going over set structures in $\Bbb R$. However I can not figure out where to start on this proof even though it is likely simple one. Even a place to start would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Cannot you show that $\frac{1}{q}\le\frac{p}{q}$?

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1}{q} \leq \frac{p}{q} < \frac{1}{n}$$